# The purpose of sklearn.pipeline Pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn

I am very curious what is the purpose of sklearn.pipeline Pipeline.

I check the online source. 
"The purpose of the pipeline is to assemble several steps that can be cross-validated together while setting different parameters."

I am still confused about this explanation. Will it improve the quality of classification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipelines are synonymous to workflows. **It does not improve the quality of classification**. It only helps in automation of machine learning workflows.

Comment: When the pipeline is been used, the 'steps' are called as well. What does the "steps" do? Standardize the scale?

Comment: Yes, the steps are automated when you call the pipeline. The steps could be pre-processing, scalling, training and evaluation.